# Bounding a complex function given a condition on its input

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $\vert z\vert = R$. Then I want to bound the function

$$f(z) = (z^2+4)^2(z^2+9)$$

from below.

---

So I have

\begin{align}
\left\vert (z^2+4)^2(z^2+9)\right\vert &= \left\vert z^2+4\right\vert^2\left\vert z^2+9\right\vert \\
&\ge \left(\vert z\vert^2 - 4\right)^2\left(\vert z\vert^2-9\right) \\
&= (R^2-4)^2(R^2-9)
\end{align}

Is this a valid approach?

Comment: Yes this a valid approach.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: what if $R<2$?

Comment: @MartinArgerami You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to make sure that your lower bound is positive. So, depending on the value of $R$, you may have to choose $9-R^2$ and/or $4-R^2$.

Comment: Ah yes that is true! Luckily here $R>3$ so we are safe :) Thanks.